# Partitioning in Pig like Hive

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Is it possible to use Partitioning feature in Pig like Hive? I mean can we Load and store data in partitions using PIG Latin?

Answer (score 0):

Pig can work with `HCatalog`'s Partitioning. We can access the data from partitioned hive tables using pig's `HCatStorage`.

Comment: That helps. Thank you Madhu.